# Acccessing element that just added to the dom via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an element that was added to the DOM via ajax.

Like `<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox'>`

I wan to change its atrribute like `$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true)`

But I cannot access the element.How do I access this dynamic element

```
 $.ajax({
    "url": url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    },
    "success": function (data) {
        $("#ajaxResultContainer").html(data);
        $('#ajaxFormModal').modal('show');
    }, complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

Comment: If you just created it in an AJAX request then surely you must have a reference to it ...? Please show us the AJAX code which creates the element.

Comment: $("#ajaxResultContainer").html(data);
 $('#ajaxFormModal').modal('show');

Comment: You run the code probably in the wrong order. Ajax is asynchronous. The callback function of the ajax request is executed when the http request returns.

Comment: In that case you just need to use `$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true)` but *after* you've updated the `html()` of the container

Comment: Notice the result is displayed in the bootstrap modal.Could this be a problem?

Comment: If the modal is an iframe it cause problems. Otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: Lately I am becoming like "Nazi" against copy-paste "JQuery" users :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    },
    "success": function (data) {
        $("#ajaxResultContainer").html(data);
        $('#ajaxFormModal').modal('show');
    }, complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```